# Find all products in Magento 2 with more than 1 product image

Tags: magento2, database, product-images

Looking for some SQL which would list all `SKU's` with more than 1 product image attached to it.

Ideally I would also like to delete all images which are not used as `base/small/thumbnail`, but happy to do that that in the backend if that's easier.

The relevant tables seem to be `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`, `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` and `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL finds all images in `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` which are not used as *base/small/thumbnail*:

```
SELECT
  gal.value_id,
  gal.value
FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery gal
  LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar ent ON ent.value = gal.value
WHERE ent.value IS NULL;
```

Exported this as text file and then created a script which deleted all entries from:

- `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`
- `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`

where `value_id` was equal to the ones in the file generated above.